# How to read encrypted email send from Outlook 365 to an outlook email address

Tags: outlook.com, encryption

I received an encrypted email in outlook probably from someone with Microsoft 365. I do not have Microsoft 365. According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/send-view-and-reply-to-encrypted-messages-in-outlook-for-pc-eaa43495-9bbb-4fca-922a-df90dee51980 I should be able to decrypt this message through a link in the email. But the email only shows me "You don't have sufficient permissions to open the mail." when opened in either webmail or through the android Outlook app.

Is there any way to open these emails?

---

(Outlook support told me no. That I need a Outlook 365 account and use the desktop app in order to be able to open these emails. This directly contradicts their own documentation so it seems they are not well informed themselves.)

Answer (score -1):

Support explains that, without access to Windows, decryption works for any email address EXCEPT outlook/hotmail ones. For these the link will not appear (as they assume you use the windows desktop application). Note that the outlook web email or android app do not support decryption either. Since I don't have a Windows device there is absolutely no way to open these emails.

So I guess in doing this Microsoft is teaching a valuable lessons never to use their products as even they themselves put compatibility with other email providers as a higher priority then support for the email addresses they themselves provide.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree that it would be good to include this. I can't find the answers I got in the support chat in official documentation though. I suspect that Microsoft is trying to hide this failing on purpose. Also unlike other support chats there is no option to save the conversation at the end. I don't think I can do anything to proof that this is what support told me. Next time I will take screenshots during the chat. I guess I can ask again just to get confirmation again. But perhaps even beter would be if someone else did it and could confirm they got the same answers from support.

Comment: This doesn't really prove anything since I could have written it myself but here is an example sentence from support substantiating my answer partially that I did happen to copy: "17:02 - Sent
Bot WC said: I am saying that it will work with the Outlook accounts however as it was being designed with the Application therefore you will need the application to open the email."